# Is there any way to treat NA differently for the same variable?

Tags: r

I have a dataset that the same ID may have several records for the same variable. Some of them have partial NA, some of them have all NA.

I want to sum the variable based on the same ID, and want people with all NA in that variable to get an NA while people with partial NA in that variable to get a sum (treat NA as 0 in this situation). Is there any way to do this?

I have tried na.rm = T when summing the variable, and all NA became 0, this is not what I want.

```r
Dataset:

ID V1
5  120
5  300
5  NA
8  NA
8  NA
8  NA

Want this:
ID V1
5  420
8  NA

I did this and all NA became 0:

df <- df %>% group_by(ID) %>% transmute(V1 = sum(V1, na.rm = T))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of the approaches would remove the `NA` group or make it 0. Maybe we can use a custom condition

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(V1 = if (all(is.na(V1))) NA else sum(V1, na.rm = TRUE))

# A tibble: 2 x 2
#     ID    V1
#  <int> <int>
#1     5   420
#2     8    NA
```

and with base R `aggregate`

```
aggregate(V1~ID, df, function(x) 
          if (all(is.na(x))) NA else sum(x, na.rm = TRUE), na.action = "na.pass")
```

Comment: The code works! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

We can use `sum_` from `hablar` which would automatically return `NA` if all the elements are `NA`.  Using `data.table` syntax, it would be

```
library(data.table)
library(hablar)
setDT(df)[, .(V1 = sum_(V1)), .(ID)]
#   ID  V1
#1:  5 420
#2:  8  NA
```

---

Or with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(ID) %>%
   summarise(V1 = sum_(V1))
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#     ID    V1
#   <int> <int>
#1     5   420
#2     8    NA
```

---

Or with `sum` without using any `if/else`

```
df %>%
   group_by(ID) %>% 
   summarise(V1 = sum(V1, na.rm = TRUE) * NA^ all(is.na(V1)))
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#     ID    V1
#  <int> <dbl>
#1     5   420
#2     8    NA
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
out <- rowsum(df$V1, df$ID, na.rm = TRUE)
(NA^!out) * out
#  [,1]
#5  420
#8   NA
```

---

Or with `by`

```
by(df$V1, df$ID, FUN = sum_)
```

NOTE: all the codes are compact

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(5L, 5L, 5L, 8L, 8L, 8L), V1 = c(120L, 300L, 
NA, NA, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L
))
```